# How to sum two float4 arrays values into a Datum array? (c function in postgres)

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

My question is about C functions in PostgreSQL, where I'm trying to receive 2 `float4[]` arrays as parameters and return a `float4[]` array as the sum of array1 + array2 (columns in tables are set as float4[] as well), but can't achieve it:

To create the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sum(float4[], float4[]) RETURNS float4[]
AS 'example.so', 'sum'
LANGUAGE C STRICT;
-- 'example.so' is already on /usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/lib
```

And the C code:

```
Datum sumar(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS);
PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(sumar);
Datum sumar(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)

{
  ArrayType *array1, *array2;

  // The array element types:
  Oid arrayElementType1, arrayElementType2;

  // The array element type widths:
  int16 arrayElementTypeWidth1, arrayElementTypeWidth2;

  // The array element type:
  bool arrayElementTypeByValue1, arrayElementTypeByValue2;

  // The array element type alignment codes:
  char arrayElementTypeAlignmentCode1, arrayElementTypeAlignmentCode2;

  // The array contents, as PostgreSQL "datum" objects:
  Datum *arrayContent1, *arrayContent2;

  // List of "is null" flags for the array contents:
  bool *arrayNullFlags1, *arrayNullFlags2;

  // The size of each array:
  int arrayLength1, arrayLength2;

  Datum *sumContent;
  int i;
  ArrayType* resultArray;

  // Extract the PostgreSQL arrays from the parameters passed to this function call.
  array1 = PG_GETARG_ARRAYTYPE_P(0);
  array2 = PG_GETARG_ARRAYTYPE_P(1);

  // Determine the array element types.
  arrayElementType1 = ARR_ELEMTYPE(array1);
  get_typlenbyvalalign(arrayElementType1, &arrayElementTypeWidth1, &arrayElementTypeByValue1, &arrayElementTypeAlignmentCode1);
  arrayElementType2 = ARR_ELEMTYPE(array2);
  get_typlenbyvalalign(arrayElementType2, &arrayElementTypeWidth2, &arrayElementTypeByValue2, &arrayElementTypeAlignmentCode2);

  // Extract the array contents (as Datum objects).
  deconstruct_array(array1, arrayElementType1, arrayElementTypeWidth1, arrayElementTypeByValue1, arrayElementTypeAlignmentCode1, &arrayContent1, &arrayNullFlags1, &arrayLength1);
  deconstruct_array(array2,arrayElementType2, arrayElementTypeWidth2, arrayElementTypeByValue2, arrayElementTypeAlignmentCode2, &arrayContent2, &arrayNullFlags2, &arrayLength2);

  //Create a new array of sum results (as Datum objects).
  sumContent = (Datum *) palloc(sizeof(Datum) * arrayLength1);

  // Generate the sums.
  for (i = 0; i < arrayLength1; i++)
  {
    sumContent[i] =  arrayContent1[i] + arrayContent2[i];
  }

  // Wrap the sums in a new PostgreSQL array object.
  resultArray = construct_array(sumContent, arrayLength1, arrayElementType1, arrayElementTypeWidth1, arrayElementTypeByValue1, arrayElementTypeAlignmentCode1);

  // Return the final PostgreSQL array object.
  PG_RETURN_ARRAYTYPE_P(resultArray);
}
```

When it returns the array at the ends, it shows me just negative values (the sum is wrong), but when I pass 2 int arrays it works fine. Also I have tried casting the values before the sum, just like:

```
sumContent[i] =  Float4GetDatum(arrayContent1[i]) + Float4GetDatum(arrayContent2[i];)
```

and

```
sumContent[i] =  DatumGetFloat4arrayContent1[i]) + DatumGetFloat4(arrayContent2[i]);
```

but it keeps giving me strange values.

Comment: Recommend you pare back the excess and only give the bare minimum to show your problem.

Comment: @AaronHall Actually, that pretty much is the minimum required to show the problem.

Answer (score 1):

After `deconstruct_array` you have an array of `Datum` values, each of which is a pass-by-value float4 represented as a `Datum`.

Adding `Datum` directly is invalid - it's an abtract type you can't actually perform operations on. If the C compiler would let us then the PostgreSQL project would make that an error, but it won't (or rather, it won't without making other things even more horrible).

To get the C `float` for a `float4`-typed `Datum` you should use `DatumGetFloat4`. `Float4GetDatum`, as you use, would be the opposite direction. Again, the project would make that an error if the C compiler would let us.

(Insert irritated grumbling about the PostgreSQL community refusing to move to a subset of C++ where we could use C++'s stricter typecasting rules to do this sort of thing here).

If you add:

```
elog(LOG, "%f", Float4GetDatum(arrayContent1[i]));
```

you should see the correct value in the logs.

To add them and store the result you want:

```
sumContent[i] = Float4GetDatum( DatumGetFloat4(arrayContent1[i]) +
                                DatumGetFloat4(arrayContent2[i]) );
```